# Improve a query of countries with the largest population in each continent

Tags: sql

World is a table of countries with rows of name, continent, and population.

I want to make a new table of continent, name for the countries with largest population in each continent.

I think the following query works. But is there a simpler/more efficient way to do this?

```sql
WITH G(cont, pop) AS (
    SELECT continent, MAX(population) FROM world
    GROUP BY continent
)
SELECT continent, name from world, G
  where continent = G.cont
        and population = G.pop
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select D.continent, D.name from 
(
  select continent , name , population , 
  max(population) over (partition by continent) maxPop
  from World
) D
where D.population=D.maxPop
```

Or:

```
select continent , name   
  from World
  where (continent, population) in
  (select continent,max(population) over (partition by continent) from World)
```

See a demo from [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7dNYQ412yijnedyv2gjZ2T/0).